# Display Each Element From Array Using HTML Helper in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

This is probably a very simple problem, but I am extremely new to C# / MVC and I have been handed a broken project to fix. So it's time to sink or swim!

I have an array of strings that is being passed from a function to the front end.
The array looks something like

```
reports = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Reports\");
```

On the front end, I would like it to display each report, but I am not sure how to do that.
This project is using a MVC, and I believe the view is called "Razor View"? I know that it's using an HTML helper.

In essence, I need something like

```
@HTML.DisplayTextFor(Model.report [And then print every report in the array]);
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the file name array you can simply use a foreach:

```
@foreach(var report in Model.Reports){ @report }
```

Note that you should add the Reports property to your view model:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{   
    public string [] Reports { get; set; }
}
```

You could use ViewData or TempData but I find that using the view model is the better way.

You can then populate it:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SampleViewModel(){ Reports = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Reports\")};
        
    return View(model);
}
```

And use it in the view as you see fit.

Here is a simple online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5WmX5M

If you'd like to add a null check at the view level you can:

```
@if(Model.Reports != null)
{   
    foreach(var report in Model.Reports){  @report <br> }
}
else
{
    <span> No files found </span>
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/melMLW

This is never a bad idea, although in this case `GetFiles` will return an empty list if no files can be found, and I assume a possible IOException is being handled.

Comment: This is perfect. I am getting an error sometimes as though the list is null - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is there a way to check for that during the display to not throw that error?

Comment: Disregard - there was a second instance of the model that I had not added the newly added report section to. Adding that fixed it. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Apolymoxic glad to help, a null check at the view level is always a handy tool, although not so necessary in this case, I added a sample to the answer.